# print value from view to controller codeigniter with ajax onchange without load page

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, codeigniter

I want to use condition view with the value from view's CodeIgniter without loading page. I tried tracking error, I give up, I don't know, what's it error

**jquery ajax:**

```
var site = '<?php echo site_url();?>';
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#comboKec").change(function (){
    var selectedText = $(this).find("option:selected").text();
    var selectedValue = $(this).val();

    //alert(selectedValue);
      //$("#res").text(site);

    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        serviceUrl: site+'anggota/index',
        data: {'kec' : selectedValue},
        success: function(data) {
            console.log(selectedValue);
        },
        error: function(msg) {
            console.log('error : '+msg);
        }
    });
  });
});
```

**html:**

```
<select>
<option value="aaaa">1</option>
<option value="bbbb">2</option>
</select>
```

**controller:**

```
$kec = $this->input->post('kec');
if($kec="aaaa"){ echo "Data 1"; }
else if($kec="bbbb"){ echo "Data 2"; }
else { echo "No Data Selected"; }
```

Comment: how do you get the value without having a name of the select dropdown ?

Comment: oh sry i forget to type it, i just make a simulation code, it has atribut  'name="kecamatan" id="comboKec"'

Comment: @RizaldySetiawanH after echoing something you need to put `;`, you have not done this in `echo "Data 1"`, `echo "Data 2"`, `echo "No Data Selected"`

Comment: i have edited my answer lets check with it !

Comment: do that for me ! after sending data to your method in your controller just get it with  $kec = $_POST['kec']; and add die() method after it and check if it is giving you something or not ?;

Comment: @M.Alim it will print die()

Answer (score 0):

i think u need to change in two place's to see difference in colsole

```
  $.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    serviceUrl: site+'anggota/index',
    data: {'kec' : selectedValue},
    success: function(data) {


     >  console.log(selectedValue);
     >             console.log(selectedValue);

    },
    error: function(msg) {
        console.log('error : '+msg);
    }
});
```

and give the name to the select as

```
 > <select name="comboKec">

<option value="aaaa">1</option>
 <option value="bbbb">2</option>
</select>
```

oh your another mistake is in $kec= "aaaa" you should use $kec=="aaaa" instead !Because with $kec= "aaaa" you are assigning value to copare you shoul use  $kec=="aaaa" !

```
  $kec = $_POST['kec'];


>  if($kec=="aaaa"){ echo "Data 1" ;}
```

> ```
> else if($kec=="bbbb"){ echo "Data 2"; }
> ```

```
else { echo "No Data Selected" ;}
```

Comment: sry about name of tag select and '=' on my php.. i make simulation code,, i on badmood with my code lol.. i just make a simulation,, it just typo..

Comment: i already following ur code, but it not working, i think, something wrong on my serviceUrl, coz it didnt print dinamically

Comment: after echoing something you need to put `;`, you have not done this in `echo "Data 1"`, `echo "Data 2"`, `echo "No Data Selected"`

Comment: $kec = $_POST['kec']; in your controller because you are sending data by ajax !

Comment: if thats not working then show ur controller's code  ! let's see what you have in it

Comment: i try used $_POST['kec']l too, it not working..
if u want help me, can u give me an email? i ll sent my complete project code

Comment: @RizaldySetiawanH no need for whole project code, just post controller code here

Comment: @RizaldySetiawanH what do you get in this? `$kec = $this->input->post('kec');`

Comment: @RizaldySetiawanH where are this methods `add_polygonA();` and  ` add_polygonA();`?

Comment: $kec = $this->input->post('kec'); from ajax data
methods polygon available.. i just want make a dinamically print data from view to controller